# skype crashes in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: skype

I am using linux, in fact I started using ubuntu when I first met computers.
 If I remember it correctly, I am using ubuntu since 4.04. I also tried other linux versions.
 
Skype worked perfectly fine all the way but in ubuntu 12.04 it crashes, skype logs in successfully but when its logged in it crashes.

Comment: any log files? anything you can tell us to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, this is what I did to overcome it:

1. Remove previous installations of skype:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skype
   ```
2. Do an overall update:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. [Download the latest version of skype](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/)

   Start Skype and it should work fine

Comment: For me this worked http://askubuntu.com/a/388731/66359

Answer (score 3):

This helped me:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386
```

From here: [Skype 4.2 extremely unstable / unusable on Debian sid](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-4-2-extremely-unstable-unusable-on-Debian-sid/td-p/1733288)

Comment: This does not help me. It still crashes every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

I run 12.04 with skype and haven't had any issues (besides the zero in the keypad not always working).

First, purge (remove) all old skype stuff:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
```

There is a new skype version (4.1). It's 32bit but runs fine on my x64 system.  To get the .deb file:

```
wget http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-ubuntu-64
```

To install the deb file you just downloaded, run this in the download directory (just  make sure it's the only .deb file there):

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**edit:** in the purge command, it should be "skype" and not "skype*"

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved for me when I removed the `~/.Skype` folder.