# Skype Freezes Sporadically

Tags: 12.04, freeze, skype, kill

I've been having the problem ever since I started using Skype on Ubuntu, some two years ago. I'm always thinking that they will fix it with the next update, but no. From time to time, it will randomly freeze eating up all free CPU time, and I have to kill it from System Monitor and re-run it. Is there a work-around for this, as I'll be soon needing my Skype to work for me without crashing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try start it from terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) using this command: `skype` . So you can see the error after crash on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is possible fix for all the versions, but I was facing same issue. I had used deb file from skype website. That always kept crashing. So I uninstalled it and installed skype from Canonical Partner repo. Its been stable ever since.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed skype using software manager install try using the one from the website: http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

If you installed skype using the website version try the terminal/software manager version: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Skype-Using-Terminal-on-Ubuntu

note: both software packages and official version should be the same, errors may occur with the different methods. Also not all ubuntu repository update as much as the website version.

I also use skype on windows 7 and it sometimes crashes my sound card and freezes for the whole day.

Comment: I got [this](http://screencloud.net/v/nYGC) while trying to replace it with the site version.